# Decoding NUMBER(38,10) into readable format (in python) coming through kafka topic

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, debezium

I am getting data from my source db through debezium connector into kafka topic. From that kafka topic I have pyspark code written to transform or mold data according to my need. I am having trouble in decoding one of its field which is id having datatype of  "NUMBER(38,10)".

My debezium source Connector configuration is as follows:

```
name=inventory-connector
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector
tasks.max=1
database.server.name=server1
database.hostname=***.**.*.*
database.port=1521
database.user=USER
database.password=PASS
database.dbname=ORCLCDB
database.pdb.name=ORCLPDB1
database.connection.adapter=logminer
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
database.history.kafka.topic=schema-changes.inventory
table.include.list=DEBEZIUM.LOGS
column.include.list=DEBEZIUM.LOG.ID,DEBEZIUM.LOG.SERVICENAME
time.precision.mode=connect
transforms=filter,route
transforms.filter.type=io.debezium.transforms.Filter
transforms.filter.language=jsr223.groovy
transforms.filter.condition=value.source.table == 'LOG'
transforms.filter.topic.regex=server1.DEBEZIUM.*
transforms.route.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter
transforms.route.regex=([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)
transforms.route.replacement=$3
```

MY SOURCE DB

```
CREATE TABLE log (
ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
SERVICENAME VARCHAR2(50),
```

MY PYSPARK code, I am getting data via kafka topic here:

```
def deserialize_avro(serialized_msg):
   data1 = json.loads(serialized_msg)
   dfMessage = data1["payload"]['after']
   
   #print(data1["payload"]['after'])

   return (
       dfMessage['ID'],
       dfMessage['SERVICENAME'],
       dfMessage['NAYAPAYID'],
       dfMessage['ACCOUNTNUMBER']
   )

def saveToMysql(currentDf, epocId):

    dbCredentials = {"user": mysql_user_name,
                     "password":mysql_password,
                     "driver":mysql_driver_class}

    print("Printing Epoc Id")
    print(epocId)

    processedAt = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    currentDfFinal = currentDf\
        .withColumn("processed_at",lit(processedAt))\
        .withColumn("batch_id", lit(epocId))

    print("Printing Before MySql Table Save: " + str(epocId))

    currentDfFinal \
        .write \
        .jdbc(url=mysqlJdbcUrl,
              table = mysql_table_name,
              mode = "append",
              properties = dbCredentials)

    print("Printing After MySql table Save " + str(epocId))

orders_df = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
        .option("subscribe", KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME) \
        .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
        .load()

orders_schema = StructType()\
        .add("ID", StringType()) \
        .add("SERVICENAME", StringType()) \
       
avro_deserialize_udf = psf.udf(deserialize_avro, returnType=orders_schema)

df = orders_df.withColumn("avro", avro_deserialize_udf(psf.col("value"))).select("avro.*")


df.writeStream \
        .trigger(processingTime='15 seconds') \
        .outputMode("update") \
        .foreachBatch(saveToMysql) \
        .start()

trans_detail_write_stream.awaitTermination()
```

Error I am facing is

**java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect integer value: 'VMgnfsfUAA==' for column 'ID' at row 1**

When I checked Topic Content I find out that Id is not coming in a right format, and I need to decode it to int or str, Content I am receiving at kafka topic is:

```
"payload":{"before":null,"after":{"ID":"fXZlaCccAA==","SERVICENAME":"ECommerce"},"source":{"version":"1.8.1.Final","connector":"oracle","name":"server1","ts_ms":1686053890489,"snapshot":"last","db":"ORCLPDB1","sequence":null,"schema":"DEBEZIUM","table":"WSLOG","txId":null,"scn":"2589081","commit_scn":null,"lcr_position":null},"op":"r","ts_ms":1686053890489,"transaction":null}}
```

Please help me to find out the way to decode this ID " {"ID":"fXZlaCccAA==" " in python to a correct format so that I can save records into my sink DB.

Comment: VMgnfsfUAA== looks like a base64 encoding. Do you know what numeric value it's meant to represent? Does the value 23863970000000000 mean anything to you?

Comment: Yes @DarkKnight 2386397 is one of the id in my db, Can you please tell me how did you decode that ? base64 decoding isnt working for me when I am working with solutions given on internet.

Comment: This code ``` base64.b64decode('VMgnfsfUAA==') ``` gives me this: "b"T\xc8'~\xc7\xd4\x00""

Answer (score 1):

You can use `base64.b64decode` and `int.from_bytes`:

```
>>> import base64
>>> a = int.from_bytes(base64.b64decode('VMgnfsfUAA=='), 'big')
23863970000000000
```

Then, since the type is `NUMBER(38, 10)`, you'll need to divide it by `10 ** 10` (if it was `NUMBER(38, 9)` that'd be `10 ** 9`) to "move the decimal dot":

```
>>> a / (10 ** 10)
2386397.0
```